# problem with position of inserted picture

Tags: includegraphics

I have problem with picture. Look position of picture in code and where overleaf put picture

```
\documentclass[a4 paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{17pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\geometry{a4paper,
left=25mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definicija}[section]
\newtheorem{nap}{Napomena}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Propozicija}[section]
\newtheorem{krl}{Korolar}[section]
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{pr}{Primjer}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}

\noindent gdje je $\phi$ funkcija gustoće standardne normalne slučajne varijable:

$$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right).$$

Vidimo da su formule za Gammu jednake za call i put opciju. U sljedećem primjeru prikazati ćemo rezultate za $\Gamma$ i $\Gamma_{P\&G}$ za pojedine promjene cijena dionice.
\begin{pr}
Neka su dani sljedeći parametri $S_0 = 1000$, $K = 1000$ kuna te neka su $r=2\%$, $\sigma=0.2$ i $\tau=1$ godina. Promotrimo rezultate za te parametre ukoliko su se dogodile sljedeće promjene cijena dionice:


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{  c | c | c | c | c | c | c } 
  S & 850 & 900 & 950 & 1000 & 1050 & 1100 \\ \hline
  \Gamma & 0.0019452 & 0.0021011 & 0.0020964 & 0.0019552 & 0.0017214 & 0.0014424 \\ \hline
  \Gamma_{P\&G} & 43.77 & 21.01 & 5.24 & 0 & 4.30 & 14.42 \\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Vrijednosti $\Gamma$ i $\Gamma_{P\&G}$ za različite početne vrijednosti dionice}
\label{tab:gamma}
\end{center}
\end{pr}

\begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{s2.png}
    \caption{An image of a galaxy}
    \label{fig:galaxy}
\end{figure}

Prethodno smo zaključili da je Gamma jednaka za call i put opciju. Iz tablice za vrijednosti $\Gamma$ vidimo da njegov graf ima zvonoliki oblik. Najveća vrijednost za Gammu je u slučaju kada je cijena dionice manja od cijene izvršenja $K$. Također možemo primjetiti kako velikom promjenom cijena od početne cijene dionice stvaramo sve veće profite.   
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need al those package? BTW, `hyperref` had to be lead last in preamble (with rare exception as is `cleveref` package), also it is sufficient if you load each package once.. For figure positionin try positioning option `\begin{figure}[!ht]` ...

Comment: It was useful, sometimes I put text in new line for positioning picture where I want